# Draw multiple spirals in the same tikzpicture environment

Tags: polar, spiral

I'm using the following code to draw a spiral using TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
    ]
    \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw two spirals in the same `tikzpicture` environment, one to the right of the other. I don't know how to set the coordinates for a `polaraxis`. I found [this page at tikz.dev](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-polar) which provides some examples on `polaraxis`, but I wasn't able to find an example that draws two `polaraxis` in the same `tikzpicture` environment.

I know that it is possible to draw one spiral to the right of another spiral by repeating the same `tikzpicture` environment (as shown below), but I want to avoid doing this since in my original document I am drawing more than 30 spirals in the same page and having multiple `tikzpicture` environments would add unnecessary lines of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
    ]
    \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
    ]
    \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In simple terms, I want to have a single `tikzpicture` environment that contain multiple spirals. The spirals don't necessarily have to use `polaraxis`. In the example above, I used `polaraxis` because I found it convenient for drawing spirals.

## The result I'm looking for

The following image was created using Inkscape. It shows the layout that I'm trying to create using TikZ.

[image]

Comment: Will they all be identical? If so, the most efficient approach would be to save one to a box and then reuse it, but that's only applicable if the 30 are actually going to be repeats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. The best option depends to some extent on what exactly you're doing. For example, are your spirals all to be identical or was that just for the example? If not, do they use the same `polaraxis` configuration? Depending on your answers, I give three methods. The point isn't that these give different output - if they do, that's incidental and not necessary at all - but that the second avoids unnecessarily duplicating code and the third also avoids unnecessarily recompiling repeated code. (TikZ is great, but it is *s-l-l-o-o-o-w*!)

[image: sample spirals]

Note that there's a problem with the images I'm pasting right now due to an Okular/KDE update. Apologies for the crappy quality.

### Case 1

If your spirals will have variations in axis configuration, you can do something like this:

```
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
    ]
    \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
  \end{polaraxis}
  \scoped[xshift=20mm]{%
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        width = 100pt,
        height = 100pt,
        axis lines = none,
        no marks,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        domain = 0:3
      ]
      \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
    \end{polaraxis}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Case 2

If the function varies, but the axis configuration remains the same, you could use something like this

```
\pgfplotsset{%
  spiral axis/.style={%
    width = 100pt,
    height = 100pt,
    axis lines = none,
    no marks,
    samples = 200,
    smooth,
    domain = 0:3,
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \makespiral { O{} m }{%
  \scoped[#1]{\begin{polaraxis}[spiral axis]\addplot+(#2);\end{polaraxis}}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \makespiral{4*180*x,x}
  \makespiral[xshift=20mm]{4*180*x,x}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where `\makespiral[<optional scope configuration>]{function/variable to plot}`.

### Case 3

If you really do need 30 identical spirals (or 81 as in your target image), I'd save te spiral to a box first and then just use it 30 (or 81) times. For example,

```
\newsavebox \spiralbox
\sbox \spiralbox {%
  \tikz{%
    \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
      ]
      \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
    \end{polaraxis}% 
  }%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,20,40,60,80,100}
  \foreach \j in {0,20,40,60,80}
  \node [anchor=north west] at (\i mm,\j mm) {\usebox\spiralbox};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Because this only compiles the plot once, it is much more efficient than repeating the same calculations for every repeat of the spiral. This is the same approach used by, for example, `tikzsymbols` to avoid unnecessarily slowing compilation.

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713114/ addaswyd o gwestion rdrg109: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713109/
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=1.18,
  spiral axis/.style={%
    width = 100pt,
    height = 100pt,
    axis lines = none,
    no marks,
    samples = 200,
    smooth,
    domain = 0:3,
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \makespiral { O{} m }{%
  \scoped[#1]{\begin{polaraxis}[spiral axis]\addplot+(#2);\end{polaraxis}}%
}
\newsavebox \spiralbox
\sbox \spiralbox {%
  \tikz{%
    \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
      ]
      \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
    \end{polaraxis}% 
  }%
}
\begin{document}
Case 1:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      width = 100pt,
      height = 100pt,
      axis lines = none,
      no marks,
      samples = 200,
      smooth,
      domain = 0:3
    ]
    \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
  \end{polaraxis}
  \scoped[xshift=20mm]{%
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        width = 100pt,
        height = 100pt,
        axis lines = none,
        no marks,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        domain = 0:3
      ]
      \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
    \end{polaraxis}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

Case 2:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \makespiral{4*180*x,x}
  \makespiral[xshift=20mm]{4*180*x,x}
\end{tikzpicture}

Case 3: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,20,40,60,80,100}
  \foreach \j in {0,20,40,60,80}
  \node [anchor=north west] at (\i mm,\j mm) {\usebox\spiralbox};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You could alternatively place `\spiralbox` without using `tikzpicture`, but this method is a probably easiest if you're familiar with TikZ already.

Answer (score 2):

- I use `pic` to store the spiral
- I use 2 nested loops (row, column) to reproduce this picture
- So that they are next to each other, I initialize the marker with `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=50pt,y=50pt]`

  ```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

   \tikzset{spiral/.pic={
       \begin{polaraxis}[
           width = 100pt,
           height = 100pt,
           axis lines = none,
           no marks,
           samples = 200,
           smooth,
           domain = 0:3
       ]
       \addplot+(4*180*x,x);
       \end{polaraxis}
   }}
   \ExplSyntaxOn

   \NewDocumentCommand{\spiral}{m m}
       {
           \begin{tikzpicture}[x=50pt,y=50pt]
           \int_step_inline:nn {#1} 
           {
               \int_step_inline:nn {#2}
                   {  
                           \pic at (####1,##1){spiral};
                           %\node at (####1,##1){####1,##1};
                   }
           }
       \end{tikzpicture}       
       }

   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \begin{document}
   \spiral{6}{9}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]